# Kryo serialisation in Chronicle Map - slow byte reading

Tags: scala, kryo, chronicle-map

I'm using Chronicle Map extensively in Scala and recently decided to experiment with Kryo serialisation. I added custom marshallers (code below) and while it reduced the size of my stores by 14G (roughly 62%), and everything still works, the speed was unacceptable.

I created a sample usecase and did a few runs on the same data

```
[Using kryo] took 6883, and then 7187, 6954, 7225, 13051
[Not using kryo] took 2326, and then 1352, 1493, 1500, 1187
```

So it's several times slower. Here's the marshaller for reading:

```
class KryoMarshallerReader[T] extends BytesReader[T] {
  val kryo = // Reference to KryoPool from Twitter's Chill library

  override def read(in: Bytes[_], using: T): T = {

    val bytes = benchmark("array allocation") {
      new Array[Byte](in.readRemaining().toInt)
    }


    benchmark("reading bytes") {
      in.read(bytes)
    }


    benchmark("deserialising") {
      kryo.fromBytes(bytes).asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  }

  override def readMarshallable(wire: WireIn): Unit = {}

  override def writeMarshallable(wire: WireOut): Unit = {}
}
```

I then averaged execution times (all in ms) over those three stages and realised that reading the bytes is the slowest:

```
               stage Average time (ms)
              (fctr)             (dbl)
1 [array allocation]         0.9432907
2    [deserialising]         0.9944112
3    [reading bytes]        13.2367265
```

Now the question is - what am I doing wrong?

I looked through the interface of `Bytes[_]` and it looks like it reads bytes one by one - is there a way to use a buffer or something magically capable of bulk loading?

**Update**: Eventually I changed array allocation + reading bytes to `in.toByteArray` but it's still slow because under the hood it copies bytes one by one. Just running reads on the map shows that byte reading is the bottleneck:

[image: benchmarks from JProfiler]

Answer (score 0):

`in.readRemaining()` of the Bytes, passed into BytesReader.read(), is not your object in serialized form, it's *more* than that. The serialized form of your object is guaranteed to start from `in.readPosition()`, but it typically end much earlier than `in.readLimit()` (as `readRemaining()` = `readLimit()` - `readPosition()`). Generally BytesReader/BytesWriter pair of implementations should care of determining the end of the object bytes itself (if it needs), e. g. see the implementation of `CharSequenceArrayBytesMarshaller` in [`BytesReader` and `BytesWriter` section of the Chronicle Map tutorial](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map#byteswriter-and-bytesreader):

```java
public final class CharSequenceArrayBytesMarshaller
    implements BytesWriter<CharSequence[]>, BytesReader<CharSequence[]> {
    ...

    @Override
    public void write(Bytes out, @NotNull CharSequence[] toWrite) {
        out.writeInt(toWrite.length); // care about writing the size ourselves!
        ...
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public CharSequence[] read(Bytes in, @Nullable CharSequence[] using) {
        int len = in.readInt(); // care about reading the size ourselves!
        ...
    }
}
```

But since your are implementing Kryo serialization which should be conceptually similar to Java standard serialization, you should probably take the source of [`SerializableReader`](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/4bcdcdb8cee4c87a677e9ee71fbf6d481b0d9277/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/serialization/impl/SerializableReader.java#L44) and [`SerializableDataAccess`](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/4bcdcdb8cee4c87a677e9ee71fbf6d481b0d9277/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/serialization/impl/SerializableDataAccess.java) and modify it to use Kryo instead of standard Java serialization (but note that those sources are LGPLv3 licensed). In particular those implementations use [`Bytes.inputStream()`](http://static.javadoc.io/net.openhft/chronicle-bytes/1.7.23/net/openhft/chronicle/bytes/StreamingDataInput.html#inputStream--) and [`Bytes.outputStream()`](http://static.javadoc.io/net.openhft/chronicle-bytes/1.7.23/net/openhft/chronicle/bytes/StreamingDataOutput.html#outputStream--) to bridge the standard Java serialization, which doesn't know about Bytes, but knows about `InputStream`/`OutputStream`, without needlessly copying bytes. I'm pretty sure Kryo supports `InputStream`/`OutputStream` as well.

Be very careful with `kryo` as an instance field of any serializer interface (`BytesReader` in your case) without implementing [`StatefulCopyable`](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map#understanding-statefulcopyable). You may easily introduce concurrency bottlenecks, or concurrency bugs (data races). Check [Understanding `StatefulCopyable` section in the Chronicle Map tutorial](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map#understanding-statefulcopyable) and [Chronicle Map custom serialization checklist](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map#custom-serialization-checklist).